# Usage of npm packages in cordova / phonegap

Tags: cordova, npm

I’m trying to add a package to my Cordova project using NPM, but either I’m doing something terribly wrong or I’m not getting the way it should work… I’m using the latest version of Cordova (v3.5.0). I have created an application:

```
cordova create TestApp
cd TestApp
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
```

Everything works perfectly, and the app appears on my Android device. Now I want to add the package ‘pako’ to my app: https://github.com/nodeca/pako. I’m still in the same directory (see above) and I enter “npm install pako”. The package is installed in “/node_modules/”.

However, when I build my application for Android (cordova build android / cordova run android / cordova prepare), none of my installed packages (in the “/node_modules/” directory) is copied to the platform specific folder “platforms/android/….”. In other words, how to use a npm package in a Cordova / Phonegap application? Shouldn’t this package be copied automatically by the cordova cli to the right platform?

Is this possible at all? Or do I have to create a manual build script using Grunt for example when I want to use npm packages? Since I can’t find any examples, I have the idea that I’m completely on the wrong track, so if anyone has a little hint to help me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use this hook and it works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877379/1243247

Comment: or this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using a hook triggered before_prepare.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615080/2728710

Comment: I use this hook and it works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877379/1243247

Answer (score 1):

Adding all installed modules is usually not what you would want because they might contain other dependencies that are not actually used in the application (like testing tools or grunt tasks). While you can use npm to download dependencies and to keep them up to date, you still need to include them manually in your app.

Grunt and grunt-contrib-copy (if you want separate files) or grunt-contrib-concat (if you want a single file, usually better for performance) would be one solution. Another one would be [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), which has support for npm modules built in.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR and simple

Use the npm package: [`cordova-import-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm)

#### Long question and DIY

You can simply
**[use a hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html)** before `cordova prepare` which is also executed upon `cordova build`, that is, when the files are assembled for compiling.

Edit your `config.xml` and add this line (not inside any platform but in the root, i.e. inside `<widget`):

```xml
<hook src="hooks/importNpmPackages.js" type="before_prepare"/>
```

Then create the file `hooks/importNpmPackages.js` with this content

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')
const twoSpaces = '  ' // for log indentation
var projectRoot

module.exports = function (context) {
  console.log(`${context.hook} : ${path.relative(context.opts.projectRoot, context.scriptLocation)}`)

  projectRoot = context.opts.projectRoot
  console.log(twoSpaces + 'Project root directory: ' + projectRoot)

  copyFile('jquery', path.join('dist', 'jquery.min.js'), path.join('js', 'res', 'jquery.min.js'))

  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'js', 'bootstrap.min.js'), path.join('js', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.js'))
  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'css', 'bootstrap.min.css'), path.join('css', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.css'))
}

function copyFile (npmPackage, // oficial name of the npm package from which the file is to be copied from
  fileRelativePath, // file path with respect to the main directory of the npm package (node_modules/<package>/)
  destFilePath) { // file's path to where it is copied, relative to the project www/ directory
  
  const packageDirFullpath = path.dirname(require.resolve(path.join(npmPackage, 'package.json')))
  const fileOriginFullPath = path.join(packageDirFullpath, fileRelativePath)
  const fileDestFullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'www', destFilePath)

  fse.copySync(fileOriginFullPath, fileDestFullPath)

  const consoleMsg = npmPackage + ': ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileOriginFullPath) + ' -> ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileDestFullPath)
  console.log(twoSpaces + consoleMsg)
}
```

As you can see in this file I am copying jquery and bootsrap files using a function `copyFile` with this syntax:

```js
copyFile(
  '<npmPackageName>',
  '<path/of/originFile/relative/to/packageDir>',
  '<path/to/destFile/relative/to/wwwDir>'
)
```

I use this in all my cordova projects and it works like a charm. That's how I see it

[image]

The hook is also triggered upon `cordova build` because `cordova build` equals to `cordova prepare && cordova compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Using tools such as Webpack and Browserify is the preferred way to achieve this. Not only do you get to use any modules in your Cordova app, but you also get awesome features such as tree-shaking and performance optimizations out of the box.