# Install node dependencies for Cordova plugin

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm writing a Cordova plugin, it has a node dependency for one of the hook scripts. Ideally when my plugin is installed:

```
$ cordova plugin add my-cordova-plugin
```

I would like it to run `npm install` if `package.json` has dependencies listed.

Does Cordova support this feature in some way? Have I missed something?

My current solution is another hook that runs `after_plugin_install`:

```
module.exports = function (context) {
    var shell = context.requireCordovaModule('shelljs');

    shell.cd(context.opts.plugin.dir);
    shell.exec('npm install');
};
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide does this help you, or not? If yes, i would provide more information as an answer.

Comment: You could add the script in the www folder and ship your plugin with it already included instead of hooking it later

Comment: Use a hook before cordova `prepare`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877379/1243247

Comment: does this module help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 2):

I you're looking for to add npm modules to your Cordova project, you don't need a plugin, juste use a simple [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) triggered `before_prepare`.

This hook will run all the npm install you need for each `cordova prepare` (also for `cordova run`, `cordova compile`, etc..).

You don't have to make a JS file for a hook, a linux shell script is enough (although it is less portable). I prefer to use juste .sh file when my only need is to do "npm install" or stuff like that.