# How can I install nodejs libraries in Cordova plugin hooks

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova plugin, I want to run some script after plugin installed. So I have `<hook type="after_plugin_install" src="scripts/afterInstall.js" />` in `plugin.xml`.

`afterInstall.js` depends on some other node libraries, how can I make sure  those libraries can be installed automatically before the execution of the script? where should I put `package.json` ?

Comment: There is a decent answer in the question of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/31290828/5820158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point plugin dependencies or devDependencies are installed from package.json.

- If your plugin requires javascript dependencies you can package them with webpack or similar and add them via `js-module` directive inside the `config.xml`.
- If you require javascript dependencies inside the hooks you can basically do the same. Package the depencencies via webpack and put them inside a js file in the `scripts` folder. Inside your hook (`afterInstall.js`) you can do a relative require (e.g., require('./dependencies.js').

I haven't found an example project which requires dependencies inside the hooks. Maybe you can defer this step to the build time of the plugin.