# Npm packages in Monaca IDE?

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, monaca

Monaca relies on Cordova, which itself relies on Npm. It is possible to use Cordova plugins in Monaca, but I would like to know how to use Npm packages in Monaca, for those functionalities for which there is no Cordova plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use npm if you develop locally, then synch your project with Monaca IDE by using Monaca CLI/Localkit. Definitely, you cannot use npm directly from Monaca IDE (mainly for security and performance reasons).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that arrives at this question looking to add npm packages to an app powered by Monaca, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24446268/1459580).  It helps to think of it not as adding npm packages to Monaca but to a Cordova app.